# Apache Cordova - cordova platform add iOS failed

Tags: ios, apache, cordova

I seriously need help in this area. This is my first time working with the iOS platform for apache cordova. I have already downloaded the latest Node.js tool and Apache Cordova on my macbook. The PATH is also set up already. I was following the Apache Cordova command line steps, and when I tried to run the following command:

```
cordova platform add ios
```

I received the following error message:

```
    /Users/metanoiasherman/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-ios/3.7.0/package/bin/create: line 80: dirname: command not found
cat: /Users/metanoiasherman/DropPositioning/../CordovaLib/VERSION: No such file or directory
Error: /Users/metanoiasherman/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-ios/3.7.0/package/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1008:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1080:5)
```

This is what my $PATH prints out in Terminal:
    /Users/metanoiasherman/./usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/

Can anyone tell me what I need to do?

I have just downloaded the Xcode command line tools and installed it already. Do I have to restart my macbook? Can someone present me with the steps I need to take to solve this and progress on?

Comment: Hey guys I managed to solve the issue already, realized its a problem with my path, I have modified it to the following and now it works fine. If anything encountered the same issue, I hope the answer helped: export PATH=“$PATH:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/”

Answer (score 2):

It might be an issue with your $PATH

Try to run

```
$PATH
```

from the terminal and check if that includes the same path stated when you run:

```
which cordova
```